# React Native not showing certain images, what can I do?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, native

I'm making a weather app that fetches weather info. It puts them into ForecastItem components and they show the hour, temperature and the image. Some of them randomly don't show the picture.

Here is the Home screen that maps the forecast into ForecastItem components:

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
  {forecastData.forecast.forecastday[0].hour.map(
    (item, index) => (
      <ForecastItem
        key={index}
        item={item}
        isDay={currentWeatherData.current.is_day}
      />
    )
  )}
</View>
```

The ForecastItem component is as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Image, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { weatherImages, weatherImagesNight } from '../constants/constants';

export default function ForecastItem({ item, isDay }) {
  return (
    <View style={[styles.forecastItem, {backgroundColor: isDay ? 'white' : 'black'}]}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>{item.time.substring(11, 13)}</Text>
      <Image
        source={
          item.is_day
            ? weatherImages[item.condition.text]
            : weatherImagesNight[item.condition.text]
        }
        style={styles.imgForecast}
      />
      <Text style={styles.text}>{item.temp_c}°C</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

constants.js is storing images' locations:

```
const sunny = require('../assets/images/sunny.png');
const clear_night = require('../assets/images/clear_night.png');
const partlycloudy = require('../assets/images/partlycloudy.png');
const partlycloudy_night = require('../assets/images/partlycloudy_night.png');
const cloudy = require('../assets/images/cloudy.png');
...etc...

export const weatherImages = {
  'Sunny': sunny,
  'Clear': sunny,
  'Partly cloudy': partlycloudy,
  ...etc...
}

export const weatherImagesNight = {
  'Sunny': clear_night,
  'Clear': clear_night,
  'Partly cloudy': partlycloudy_night,
  ...etc...
}
```

The problem is some of them are showing the forecast image just fine and some of them are empty.

This is how it looks like:
[image]

I tried hardcoding path to the image in ForecastItem's Image source attribute, for example

```
<Image source={require('../assets/images/fog.png')} />
```

Now, all of the forecast items were showing an icon of fog. The interesting part is, when i Ctrl+Z'd to the previous state, the same forecast items that were missing the icon now had that fog icon even though that is not the correct weather. That would mean the image is not even updating and that's the reason why it's not showing. I have no idea what else to do to fix it.

Here is a demonstration on Youtube on how it works, I added so that weather in text is shown on each forecast item: [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/xrzv05IURpk)

You can see the weather on Miami is shown wrong the second time I open it in the forecast items that were empty the first time I viewed it.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: the problem was in the whitespace from the api's text and it could not match the key in constants.js, I added `.replace(/\s/g,'')` to the image source and deleted spaces in the constants, now it's working as it should.